# Environment Variable for AppData\Local / Access Downloaded custom assemblies

Tags: windows-7, tfsbuild, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to setup my TFS2010 Build and I want to access the files that are downloaded via the "Version control path to custom assemblies".

From what I can tell those files are downloaded to:

`C:\User\<Build User>\AppData\Local\BuildAgent\<Built Agent Number>`

I can directly access that folder via the above path, but it would be nice if there was an environment variable (or something I can use in the build) to access that folder indirectly.

Or... Is there a better way to get at these files?  (I am putting a version file in there to be downloaded every time the build is run).

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use `%LOCALAPPDATA%` *environment variable*. It expands to

> RootDrive:\User\LoggedInUser\AppData\Local

Example: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\BuildAgent`

---

Note that `%APPDATA%` will expand to

> RootDrive:\User\LoggedInUser\AppData\**Roaming**

Comment: Deriving from %appdata% environment variable, I tried to guess it as %appdatalocal% assuming local is a sub-directory inside `appdata` directory. I gave up thinking such an environment variable might not exist. Thanks for the answer. +1

Comment: For WINDOWS 10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables